# Наследование в entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Работаю через Entity Framework Code First
Есть две сущности:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Plan { get; set; }

    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInOrder : Product
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public int? OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Как организовать отдельно выборку Products и ProductsInOrder

Comment: Потому что так устроено [Наследование в EF](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.1.php), прочитайте, а потом задавайте вопрос. Пока у вас вопроса нет.

Comment: @AK изменил вопрос.

Comment: Обращаться к dbContext.ProductsInOrder пробовали? ) Давайте я скажу главное: судя по названию Products-in-order вы должны отказаться от наследования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужно тут наследование.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderPosition> OrderPositions { get; set; }
}

public class OrderPosition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Буду пробовать.