# Реализация корзины магазина в EntityFramework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

База данных интернет магазина. Есть два класса. `User` и `Book`. Хочу создать третий класс `Order`, в который буду помещать заказы. Проблема вот в чем. У одного пользователя в заказе может быть множество книг, но как это описать в EF? C помощью допкласса `UserBookOrder` я не знаю как сделать чтобы у в одном заказе было множество книг

```
public class UserBookOrder
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }

        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
    }


    public class User
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }

        }

    public class Book
        {
            public int BookId { get; set; }
            public string View { get; set; }
            public string Fio { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820482/213987), можете считать что Book = Product.

Comment: Скачайте open source проект магазина любого на asp .net. И смотрите как там это реализовано.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе у вас все верно описано. Для решения вашей задачи, необходим дополнительный класс, по вашему Order, который будет в себе хранить UserId и BookId всех пользователей и отмеченных продуктов. В итоге по ссылке на пользователя вы сможете получить все книги,а точнее их Id, и уже по Id получить название книги.

```
public class Order()
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public int BookId {get;set;}
}
```

Получить все книги у пользователя

```
var UserBook = Order.Where(o=>o.UserId == UserId).ToList();
```

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить конкретику в виде кода.

Comment: `public int BookId {get;set;}`  - здесь, увы, нет множества книг.

Comment: @Kirill 'luridSNK' F. Здесь мы получим все id книг, потом обратиться ко всей коллекции книг и вычленить от туда необходимые нам не составит труда, я думаю это тривиальные манипуляции, поэтому не стал приводить примеры. А код приведенный вами ниже в корне не верен, хотя бы потому что вы не реализуете такое в БД

Comment: @Unnamed Будьте добры, пройдите по ссылке, которую я оставил в начале своего поста. вам тоже рекомендую.

Comment: @Unnamed Понимаете в чем проблема...Согласно вашему коду `Order.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.UserId == UserId).ToList();` вы делаете это - `выбрать первый или дефолтный Order...` (в котором только 1 id на книгу) `... , где userId равен 'myUserId', а потом запхнуть его в лист` (преисполненным чувством гордости за свой код). Вот где действительно код "в корне не верен". Потому что в вопросе явное указание на получение КОЛЛЕКЦИИ данных(в данном случае книг).

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F.  все верно. Мне нужно получить коллекцию

Comment: @Unnamed, как в Вашем примере получить заказ?

Comment: @Radzhab значит советую вам присмотреться к моему ответу :)

Answer (score 0):

[Рекомендую](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.7.php).

```
public class Order()
{
    // можно будет получить заказ по id
    public int Id {get;set;} 


    // ссылка на юзера, что б было удобней к нему обращаться из корзины, например
    public User User {get;set;} // или UserId


    // Хотя многие, в том числе и я, рекомендовали бы пользоваться ICollection<Book>.
    public IEnumerable<Book> BooksInOrder {get;set;} 
}
```

И теперь данную сущность из базы можно тащить запросом по Id заказа:

```
// где Orders - коллекция всех ваших заказов
Orders.FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.id == myOrderId);
```

Либо по Id юзера:

```
Orders.FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.User == myCurrentUser);
```

Таким образом, вы получите и `User`'a и коллекцию заказанных `Books` в контексте конкретного заказа.

**UPD:** Так же, имело бы смысл(если есть необходимость), в этом классе `Order` добавить поле `DateTime OrderDate`, для того, что бы не было необходимости тянуть обо всех заказах по конкретному `User`'у.

> Например:
>
> `//заберем сегодняшние заказы
>      Orders.FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.OrderDate == DateTime.Today);`
>
> `// заберем заказы от 5 дней назад до сегодняшнего
>      Orders.FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.OrderDate <= DateTime.Today && ord.OrderDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5));`
>
> `// заберем сегодняшний заказ(ы) конкретного пользователя
>      Orders.FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.User.Id == MyUser && ord.OrderDate == DateTime.Today);`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Тут подводный камень выскочил. Почему то в таблице Book вышел столбец Order_OrderId. Никак не пойму откуда он появился

Comment: @Radzhab могу предположить, что в вашей модели `Book` есть поле `Order`. Проверьте код миграции. Возможно, была допущена ошибка в использовании моего решения, т.к. вряд ли это как-либо связано с моим ответом.

И не забудьте отметить правильный ответ :)

Comment: А где миграции?  У меня Winforms приложение. Базу удалял - результат тот же

Comment: Вы не ответили, есть ли в модели `Book` поле `Order`.
И каким образом вы вообще вносите изменения в базу данных, при изменении моделей? Убиваете базу?
Просто, создаётся стойкое ощущение, что вы не применяете никаких изменений к контексту БД.