# Как правильно записать List<string> в БД с помощью Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Нужна база с такими двумерными списками, как ее правильно записать? 
Вряд ли получится сделать `public DbSet<List<List<string>>> lst { get; set; }` (я не пробовал)

Вот был класс Темы, для записи объектов которого уже есть таблица (кроме записи материалов)

```
public class Theme: Model // Model содержит в себе строчные свойства
{
    #region Свойства
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Materials { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Path Parent { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Думаю переделать так

```
public class Theme: Model
{
    #region Свойства
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Path Parent { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Link {get;set;}

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Theme Parent { get; set; } //класс агрегатор

}
```

И запишу такие классы в бд

Comment: `string[n,2]` то есть у вас n строк, в каждой по 2 столбца?

Comment: Храните сериализованным в JSON. Образец для вдохновения посмотрите тут: [В EF поддержки коллекций нет, но она легко эмулируется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/789093/213987). Всё равно толковый поиск по этому полю вы не сделаете и индексы не расставите.

Comment: @tym32167 да, у меня список из матриц с n строками и 2 столбцами

Comment: (Не вижу смысла писать полноценный ответ, пока не будет ясно, как вы будете отличать эти списки, им же нужен будет какой-то идентификатор - или это у вас будет свойством какой-то другого объекта) Уточните вопрос, пока вопрос прямо кандидат на закрытие.

Comment: Вот мне в определенном классе проекта WPF надо хранить список учебных материалов(название и ссылка), я могу в принципе создать класс EdMaterials, что будет иметь два поля типа string: название и ссылка. И эти объекты как раз вставлять в бд, а связь с родителем будет один ко многим (через ссылку на родителя в дочернем классе, а в родительском сделать список этих объектов как раз).
@AK так подойдет же?

Comment: Связь с родителем? Что такое "родитель" для EdMaterials и куда у вас подевались ваши спискиспискков? У меня по мере чтения как вы описывали EdMaterials было стойкое ощущение, что вы эти спискисписков запихнёте полем у EdMaterials, но нет. Непонятно, поясните. И рекомендую в вопрос добавить описание этих классов, а не в комментариях описывать их.

Comment: @AK да, я неправильно выразился, родителем я назвал класс агрегатор. И в изначальном вопросе ошибка, я хотел как раз разные List<string> записывать в таблицу, код залью через час, в дороге.

Comment: Хорошо, подожду, но вероятнее всего код будет практически таким же, как в том вопросе, что я привёл по ссылке, поэтому подумайте - может быть вас устроит закрытие как дубликата.Альтернативно вам можно хранить это во вспомогательной таблице (один-ко-многим) - зависит от того, рассматриваете вы эти строки как отдельные сущности или как value object'ы и того, нужно ли вам в запросах делать поиск по этому полю. (оно конечно индекс по строке не особо эффективен, но всяко лучше, чем по json'у искать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, после уточнения задача выглядит как самое обычное отношение один-ко-многим.

Ну вот как я показываю обычно на примере продукта, заказа и позиции заказа: у одного заказа может быть несколько позиций ([тынц1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820482/213987)) или у одного бренда может быть несколько продуктов ([тынц2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/832844/213987)). Подход в рамках типичного мышления крудоделателя и формошлёпа: всё унифицировано, одинаково.

Также альтернативно вы можете просто сериализовать весь список целиком, скажем в json, и хранить его там целиком. (Пример кода можно посмотреть [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/789093/213987)) Подход удобен для [value object](https://habr.com/post/275599/)'ов, когда вам особо не нужны эти строки вне контекста вашего root объекта.